# Multiply count for many items in query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT
   `i`.`itemtype` AS `Item`,
   `p`.`name`
   SUM(`i`.`count`) AS `Count`
FROM `player_items` AS `i`
LEFT JOIN `players` AS `p` ON (`p`.`id` = `i`.`player_id`)
WHERE `i`.`itemtype` IN (2148, 2152, 2160)
   AND `i`.`player_id` = " . intval ( $main_Char->getId() ) . "
GROUP BY `i`.`itemtype`
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Is there a possibility to multiple a count for each items it select? I mean `WHERE` 
i`.`itemtype`IN (2148, 2152, 2160)`
It does SUM the count of all items of ID: `2148, 2152, 2160` I need it to do the same but additionally multiply the count of each item: `2148 * 10`, `2152 * 1000`, `2160 * 10000` and then display the results in the `Count` row.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify with some data. What the query returns now and what you want it to.

Comment: @ypercube Please look at my comment in your answer. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can `SUM` multiple columns at once:

```
SELECT i.itemtype AS Item
   , p.name
   , SUM(CASE 
            WHEN itemtype = 2148 THEN i.count
            ELSE 0
         END) * 10 AS Count
   , SUM(CASE
            WHEN itemtype = 2152 THEN i.count
            ELSE 0
         END) * 1000 AS Count1
   , SUM(CASE
            WHEN itemtype = 2160 THEN i.count
            ELSE 0
         END) * 10000 AS Count2
FROM player_items AS i
LEFT JOIN players AS p ON i.player_id = p.id
WHERE i.itemtype IN (2148, 2152, 2160)
GROUP BY i.itemtype ASC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

To SUM those three columns together, you could:

```
SELECT t.itemType AS Item, t.Count, t.Count1, t.Count2
   , SUM(t.Count1, t.Count2, t.Count3) AS Total
FROM
(
   SELECT i.itemtype AS Item
      , p.name
      , SUM(CASE 
               WHEN itemtype = 2148 THEN i.count
               ELSE 0
            END) * 10 AS Count
      , SUM(CASE
               WHEN itemtype = 2152 THEN i.count
               ELSE 0
            END) * 1000 AS Count1
      , SUM(CASE
               WHEN itemtype = 2160 THEN i.count
               ELSE 0
            END) * 10000 AS Count2
   FROM player_items AS i
   LEFT JOIN players AS p ON i.player_id = p.id
   WHERE i.itemtype IN (2148, 2152, 2160)
   GROUP BY i.itemtype ASC
   LIMIT 0, 30
) AS t
```

Or you could add another `CASE`

```
SELECT i.itemtype AS Item
   , p.name
   , SUM(CASE 
            WHEN itemtype = 2148 THEN i.count
            ELSE 0
         END) * 10 AS Count
   , SUM(CASE
            WHEN itemtype = 2152 THEN i.count
            ELSE 0
         END) * 1000 AS Count1
   , SUM(CASE
            WHEN itemtype = 2160 THEN i.count
            ELSE 0
         END) * 10000 AS Count2
   , SUM(CASE
            WHEN itemtype = 2148 THEN (i.count * 10)
            WHEN itemtype = 2152 THEN (i.count * 1000)
            WHEN itemtype = 2160 THEN (i.count * 10000)
            ELSE 0
         END) AS Total
FROM player_items AS i
LEFT JOIN players AS p ON i.player_id = p.id
WHERE i.itemtype IN (2148, 2152, 2160)
GROUP BY i.itemtype ASC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want. Perhaps this:

```
SUM(i.`count`) * COUNT(*) AS `Count`
```

or this:

```
SUM(i.`count`) * i.itemtype AS `Count`
```

Comment: The query does `SUM` a count row of each item with ID: `2148, 2152, 2160` I wan't it to do the same , but multiply each `SUM`, fe. If the `SUM` for item id `2148` is 53 I wan't to multiply it by 10 so the result in the `Count` row will be `530` instead of `53`, and should do the same with other item ids.